# How to correctly plot the floating numbers in text format in matplotlib piechart?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, floating-point, integer

I have done a clustering algorithm and represented the results in a pie chart as shown below.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))
contents  = []

for k,v  in clusters.items():
    indi= str(len(clusters[k])) + " users " +  "Cluster_"+ str(k)
    contents.append(indi)

#contents = ['23 users Cluster_0', '21 users Cluster_1']

data = [float(x.split()[0]) for x in contents]
Cluster= [x.split()[-1] for x in contents]


def func(pct, allvals):
    absolute = int(pct/100.*np.sum(allvals))
    return "{:.0f}%\n({:d} users)".format(pct, absolute)


wedges, texts, autotexts = ax.pie(data, autopct=lambda pct: func(pct, data),
                                  textprops=dict(color="w"))

ax.legend(wedges, Cluster,
          title="CLuster",
          loc="center left",
          bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0, 0.5, 1))

plt.setp(autotexts, size=10, weight="bold")

ax.set_title("Distribution of users: A pie chart")
```

Even though the users are **23 and 21** in each cluster, the piechart shows **22 and 20**. In the **def func()** int conversion is not rounding up the number to the closest, that is, if it is 22.9, it is showing as 22. Shouldn't it be 23 if it has to round up?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change `int()` to `int(`[`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round)`)`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))
contents  = []


contents = ['23 users Cluster_0', '21 users Cluster_1']

data = [float(x.split()[0]) for x in contents]
Cluster= [x.split()[-1] for x in contents]


def func(pct, allvals):
    absolute = int(round(pct/100.*np.sum(allvals)))
    return "{:.0f}%\n({:d} users)".format(pct, absolute)


wedges, texts, autotexts = ax.pie(data, autopct=lambda pct: func(pct, data),
                                  textprops=dict(color="w"))

ax.legend(wedges, Cluster,
          title="CLuster",
          loc="center left",
          bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0, 0.5, 1))

plt.setp(autotexts, size=10, weight="bold")

ax.set_title("Distribution of users: A pie chart")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I had done this. Will this lose out values if the value is in the middle like 22.5? I mean, is this an efficient way of doing it? 
`def func(pct, allvals):
    absolute = int(round(pct/100.*np.sum(allvals)))
    return "{:.0f}%\n({:d} users)".format(pct, absolute) `

Comment: @PH `round` rounds to nearest even number, so `round(22.5) == 22` and `round(77.5) == 78`, so no. But if there are more than two divisions, there could be cases such as this: `round(22.5) == 22, round(22.5) == 22, round(0.5) == 0, round(54.5) == 54` so sum = 98, instead of 100, so you need to be careful there.

Comment: exactly. I am worried about that. Is there any other way where I can show the numbers directly from the list rather than calculating the percentage and again calculating the numbers?